# Column vector's size not set to 1 for the number of columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, vector, spyder

I work on Spyder (Python 3.5) and I used pandas to study a data frame from which I took a specific column of *N* lines. However, when I convert this data frame column to a numpy array with *to_numpy()*, the size appears to be "(N, )" with *np.shape()* and the number of columns isn't set. Obviously, it should be set to 1 but it's not the case, there is simply no value after the comma.

Also, the type is an array of float64 and since the column I took is one I created using a math formula and added to the data frame, I used *fillna(0)* to suppress the NaN values in my column.

The thing is it causes me troubles when I want to do matrix multiplications after.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you upload some sample data? df.to_numpy() of a single column dataframe gives the correct shape. I.e can't replicate your issue

Comment: regarding the shape :```df['col'].to_numpy()``` will return a numpy array representing the values in this specific column (no other columns values will be taken) so the shape of this array will be the same as the shape of the column (this means nbr of values in it). regarding the nan, you need to explain more

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to upload data here. I have the csv file I'm working on but how can I share it to you?

Comment: Concerning the NaN values, I just set them to 0, so the number of values in my column stays the same.